# send formData and other object from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax query to send a form "have an upload file input" to a php file,

to send the file a formData like that :

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $("#logo").get(0).files[0];
formData.append("logo", file);
```

and I have other input values that I wanna send with it which is name , password,email ... and here is the object I created for that :

```
{name:name, email:email, password:password, auth:auth}
```

so I'm asking how to send the formData + this object as data in ajax here :

```
$.ajax({
    data :  ...... ?
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to append each element within the serialized form data into the `formData` object.

Refer here: [Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax)

Comment: thanks for the answer , I tried it but the serialized data dosen't sent , and this is for the multiple file ! I have only 1 file to upload not multiple , how can I do this ?

thanks.

Comment: Regardless whether multiple or single files, the logic is there. you must iterate through each value within the `serialize()` data and append it to the `formData` object.