# Image Upload to PHP Via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an image upload field in my application based on this question:
[Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax) 

and this tutorial:
http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/ 

I have heard it is quite difficult, this is what i have tried.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="logo_upload">
    <input type="file" name="logo_location" id="logo_location" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" name="file_test" id="file_test">Test Upload</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#logo_upload').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file_data = $('#logo_location')[0].files[0];
    formData.append("file", file_data[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../../controllers/ajax_controller.php?action=image_upload",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData ,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        id: id
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
```

As you can see, I haven't got to the uploading side of things yet.

**Result**

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>
```

I can't see what i am doing wrong, I am getting a result so it is getting to the right place, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** added #logo_upload in form
var file_data = $('#logo_location')[0].files[0];

**EDIT:** replaced data with formData variable

**EDIT:** added attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data"

**New Result:**

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'file' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'undefined'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: Point you in the right direction to what?

Comment: Silly question, but are you uploading the images, then manually browsing to http:// .. ../../../controllers/ajax_controller.php to view the dumps?

Comment: as in via a php request? no. the var_dump() is actually echoed back to the browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `file_data[0]` to the formdata object,  `file_data` is the file not an array, use `file_data`.

```
$('#logo_upload').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file_data = $('#logo_location')[0].files[0];
    formData.append("file", file_data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../../controllers/ajax_controller.php?action=image_upload",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData ,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

also you can instantiate the form data object with the form in question instead of doing the append.

```
$('#logo_upload').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
    ...
```

Comment: This was the way i thought it was supposed to be done but still nothing. I will double check now. How can i make sure that `formData` contains any data?

Comment: There is no way to, you can check your network tab in your developer tools to see what the browser sends though.

Comment: Ok that is extreamly useful, this is what chrome says was sent: `------WebKitFormBoundarysPx8WQQBwHAQAkPc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_0061.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarysPx8WQQBwHAQAkPc--`
so i guess the image was sent? Now why is my script not receiving it :|

Comment: No it still dumps an empty array

Comment: This is the correct answer, after checking upload without ajax I found the image I was uploading was too large!

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see logo_upload id in your form.
2. When uploading a file enctype="multipart/form-data" is must in form attributes.
3. data parameter in your ajax getting a variable i.e. not defined. Look at your reference link once again.

Hope this would help you

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, i have tried this still now i am getting: `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  'file' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'undefined'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
</pre>`

Comment: #2 didn't help ? This one is the necessary part as well

Comment: Yes it helped i think because now i am getting 'undefined' rather than just 'empty'

Comment: I think you should try `$("#logo_location").val()` instead of `$("#logo_location").get(0).files`

Comment: I tried this, I now get 'C' instead of 'undefined'... this is from `var_dump($_POST)` by the way.

Comment: Turns out that 'C' is part of 'C:\fakepath\IMG_0061.JPG' as i was looking at `file_data[0]` not just `file_data` and although having the file name is very nice... where is the damn data? because its certainly not in $_FILES global.

Comment: The form's attributes are totally irrelevant in ajax.

Comment: I thought this but didn't want to argue. as i was being helped :)

Comment: `data : new FormData($("#logo_location")[0])` this can help

Comment: Wish it could but we're back to empty now :(

Comment: This would help you http://runnable.com/UZKDAYo3XEw2AACX/how-to-upload-a-file-using-jquery-for-php

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong variable here and you are not defining success in your ajax request:

```
$('#logo_upload').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($('#your_form_id')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "../../../controllers/ajax_controller.php?action=image_upload",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
});
```