# Text Content and FileUpload with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asyncfileupload

I am writting a client database system for my company. Not much fancy stuff, but it does what it should.
Now that all the basic "text" stuff is done I want to add some filemanagement into it.

I have several forms which get send to the backend with ajax and then written into the db in the model.

Some of these forms are planned to have a document file upload.

Is there a way to handle normal value submits and a file submit with AJAX ?

Let me give you a FORM example:

```
<form action="SOMEPATH/LOGIC_FILE.php" action="POST" enctype= multipart/form-data>
  <label for="name">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
  </label>
  <label for="somethingElse">
   <input type="text" id="somethingElse" name="somethingElse" />
  </label>
  <label for="fileUpload">
    <input type="file" />
  </label>
</form>
```

AJAX example:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var somethingElse = $('#somethingElse').val();

var dataArr = { 'name':name, 'somethingElse':somethingElse};
MYELEMENT.click(function(e){
e.preventEventDefault();
$.ajax({
            url: "PATH/logic/logic_update_client_allg.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: allgArray,
            success: function(dataArr){
                // works
            },
            error: function(){
                // doesnt work
            }
        });
}
```

Thats how I handle my INPUT VALUE submit

How can I proceed to also upload a file with this form

**Thank you**

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax/29774331#29774331

Comment: If IE8 / IE9 support is not required, you should check the javascript `FormData()` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ajax uploads you need to use `xmlHttpRequest` which is already available in the `jQuery.ajax()` method, but with use of `FormData`.

If you are not targeting IE legacy versions, like 7,8 you can use `FormData`. One thing to be noticed that you have to set `contentType, processData` to `false`.

See the example below:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var somethingElse = $('#somethingElse').val();
var fd = new FormData();
var dataArr = {
  name: name,
  somethingElse: somethingElse,
  file : fd.append('file', $('#fileUpload').get(0).files[0]) // put the file here
};

MYELEMENT.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "PATH/logic/logic_update_client_allg.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataArr, //<----post here the files and other values
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(dataArr) {
      // works
    },
    error: function() {
      // doesnt work
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I have enhanced my javascript with the file part -> the success function gets triggered althoug I dont get anything when i try to alert my array 

Now I don't even know if it gets POSTed properly and how the file entry even looks like :s

Comment: also when I try to console log the file I get a plain undefined

Comment: not sure if it works -- check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery malsup form plugin to send files using AJAX

https://github.com/malsup/form