# Submit text-data AND file to php script with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass the input of an HTML form to a PHP script with jQuery, but all that happens is a refresh of the page. The PHP script called by this form returns a formatted div which contains all the post data. How can I display this data in the page without reloading it?

**jQuery**

```
$("form#submissionform").submit(function(){
  var formData = new FormData($(this));
  $.ajax({
    url: 'handlers/upload.php',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      $("#submissionform").html(data);
    }});
  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <form id="submissionform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Title: <p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="songtitle"><br>
    <p>Artist: </p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="artist"><br>
    <p>YouTube Link(s): </p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="ytlinks" cols="50"><br>
    <p>Other Info </p><br><textarea style="width:100%" name="otherinfo" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Bitte alle zusätzlichen Informationen hier eintragen"></textarea><br>
    <p>Select file to upload:</p>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br><br>
    <button>Send Form</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Prevent default form submission `.submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); ...` Moreover, `async: false` doesn't seem to be a good idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Content and FileUpload with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161862/text-content-and-fileupload-with-ajax)

Comment: Duplicate of [Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

Comment: @ettanany I have seen both posts and tried what was mentioned but it still doesn't work, that's why I asked this question, aware that it might look like a duplicate

Comment: @stendarr Please, check my answer below and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make an id on your button.If you use submit it will refresh your page.

```
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Then

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var formData = new FormData($(this));//Here I'd like to suggest you send the data using variable .I'm giving one exmple then do like that

<p>Title: <p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="songtitle" id="songtitle"><br>

var songTitle = $("#songtitle").val().trim();
```

In similar way you can do.

```
<p>Artist: </p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="artist" id="artist"><br>

var artist = $("#artist").val().trim();
var formData = {
    artist : artist,
    songTitle : songTitle
}



$.ajax({
    url: 'handlers/upload.php',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      $("#submissionform").html(data);
    }});
  });
```

Comment: doesn't .val() on the file input field only return its name? I wanted to pass the whole file to the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) but all that happens is a refresh of the page. (...)

In order to prevent page refreshing, you have to prevent default form submission. If the `<button>` inside a form has no `type` attribute specified or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value, it's treated as `type=submit`, which - naturally - will submit the form as a HTTP POST request (reloading page).

The following code should work for you:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="submissionform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Title: <p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="songtitle"><br>
    <p>Artist: </p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="artist"><br>
    <p>YouTube Link(s): </p><br><input style="width:360px" type="text" name="ytlinks" cols="50"><br>
    <p>Other Info </p><br><textarea style="width:100%" name="otherinfo" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Bitte alle zusätzlichen Informationen hier eintragen"></textarea><br>
    <p>Select file to upload:</p>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br><br>
    <!-- The button has no "type" attribute specified, so it's treated as type="submit" : -->
    <button>Send Form</button>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("form#submissionform").submit(function(event){

    // prevent default form submission:
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'handlers/upload.php',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**handlers/upload.php:**

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " " . $value . "\n";
    }
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $res = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    echo $res;
?>
```

**Note:** In my case, I have **uploads** folder inside handlers folder.

---

References:

- [**`event.pReventDefault()`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
- [button `type` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type)

Comment: still doesn't work, neither file nor other input is uploaded, and everything that happens is a page reload