# How to submit attr value and form values with POST using JQuery and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form with an input box and an 3 of a type of `div` that highlights when clicked. I'm trying to get it to submit the attribute and "#email" value and email it to me via PHP.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form" class="custompurchase" action="custom.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="40" class="textbox2" placeholder="Email address" required/>
    <a class="customoption storage" onclick="activate(this, 'storage');" data-name="500GB HDD">
        ...
    </a>
    <a class="customoption storage" onclick="activate(this, 'storage');" data-name="1TB HDD">
        ...
    </a>
    <a class="customoption storage" onclick="activate(this, 'storage');" data-name="2TB HDD">
        ...
    </a>
</form>
```

Here's my JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#form');
    $(form).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var storage = $(".customoptionactive.storage").attr("data-name");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr("action"),
            data: email, storage
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

And finally my PHP:

```
<?php
    $emailto = "purchases@prismpc.net";
    $subject = "Custom PC";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $storage = $_POST['storage'];
    $entire = "Email: ".$email."\n"."Storage: ".$storage;
    mail($emailto, $subject, $entire);
?>
```

However, when I see the email, this is all I get:

```
Email:
Storage:
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to set the `dataType`? Thank you so much for your answers!

Edit: Different from similar question because it was a simple syntax error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `data` option on your `$.ajax`

```
 data: email, storage
```

to

```
 data: {email:email, storage:storage}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver. I've spent HOURS on this and could not figure it out. I'll accept as best answer as soon as I can :D

Comment: @KyleHorkley Glad i helped.  :)

Comment: if you don't mind, could you explain how this fixed it? I understand with the curly brackets, but what is the ":" doing to help?

Comment: @KyleHorkley since on your `php` your accessing it through `$_POST['email']`..  you should also name the `email` value with `email`.  converting it to an `input` on a normal post submition it should look like `<input type="text" name="email" value="" />`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: normally you could also do  `data : $('Your_form').serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `FormData` and append custom data to it, as manta pointed it out here: [Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('storage', $(".customoptionactive.storage").attr("data-name"));

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(form).attr("action"),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
    ...
});
```

this will save you time adding those input values manually