# Jquery send post form ajax not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

am try to send form ajax like this code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#non").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { title: $('#mak').val(),meaning: $('#za').val()} );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
      });
    });
 </script>
```

it not alert success,and i check action after click button is ok

Comment: So there's no alert? Did you check the console for errors, and make sure the page doesn't actually reload when you submit the form

Comment: yes page not reload still form page

Comment: Please show view page too @NonBrazilian

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RpLufQCK

Comment: Oh. Is It YII framework ??

Comment: help me please am try for hour

Comment: I am writing answer. wait for 5 minute.

Comment: Did you try using `always()` instead of `done()` to be sure request is even sent and returns? Normally you should check it in developer tools of whatever browser you are using but you can as well do it this way.

Comment: jquery-1.12.3.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/index/saveedit 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It is because when you use $.post, javascript send POST request and go to next line. Javascript dont wait for $.post response! You need to use done in $.post.

Comment: @NonBrazilian Test my idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `jquery.min.js` added. Then please ignore it. Else add it. To get `action` of `<form>` Use `var action_url = form.attr('action');`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#non').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();
    var action_url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
      url: action_url,
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Oops..!! Problem Ocurred. Please Try Again..!!");
      }
  });
});  
</script>
```

**User's Requirement**

```
<script>
$('#non').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
    var val2 = $('#text2').val();
    var action_url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
      url: action_url,
      type: "POST",
      data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
      success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Oops..!! Problem Ocurred. Please Try Again..!!");
      }
  });
});
```

Or, check [Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax)

**Additional**

```
<script>
$('#non').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();
        var title_f = $('#mak').val();
    var meaning_f = $('#za').val();
        formData.append(title,title_f);
        formData.append(meaning,meaning_f);
    var action_url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
      url: action_url,
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Oops..!! Problem Ocurred. Please Try Again..!!");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: another if i want to send variable from this code but it is not form from. like variable in javascript how can i implement it

Comment: i mean add variable in script to var formData

Comment: Wait for 5 Minutes @NonBrazilian

Comment: I edited my answer in **User's Requirement** section. Please have a look. I am going from office. Can't be online. So, keep trying. *Keep Coding.* @NonBrazilian

Comment: If not getting, then please click that link which I edited in my answer. You will know @NonBrazilian

Comment: data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 }, text1 text2 mean ? i have fail

Comment: Please check latest answer. I updated. Now, you will understand @NonBrazilian. And, please follow that link.

Comment: alert Oops..!! Problem Ocurred. Please Try Again.. i check title_f meanig_f is correct data why it not work

Comment: Please see my edited answer @NonBrazilian: Good night.

Comment: error on browser Computer:93 Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach your Handler directly to the Submit-Button & do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#submitBtn").on("click", function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM... THE $(this) VARIABLE POINTS TO THE BUTTON, NOT FORM.   
  var $form = $( this ).parentsUntil("form").parent("form"),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { title: $('#mak').val(),meaning: $('#za').val()} );

  /* Alerts the results */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
});
```