# Serialize form and combine with other value in ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have Ajax like this.

```
 var idlapkondisi = $('#id_laporan_pemeriksa').val();
  var data = $('#myFormkondisi').serialize();
  $.ajax({
                type:'ajax',
                method:'POST',
                url:url,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){

                },
                error:function(response){
                 console.log(response);
                }
              })  
})
```

how can i make 2 value in ajax data while the value is a serialize data form ?
does the format like this ?

```
 data:{data,idlapkondisi:idlapkondisi},
```

Comment: Use the same variable, like `data['idlapkondisi'] = idlapkondisi;`, and then in your ajax call `data: data`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Hackerman, didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use serializeArray instead of serializing.

```
var idlapkondisi = $('#id_laporan_pemeriksa').val();
var data = $('#myFormkondisi').serializeArray();
data.push({name: "idlapkondisi", value: idlapkondisi});

$.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add that value to you payload:

```
var idlapkondisi = $('#id_laporan_pemeriksa').val();
var data = $('#myFormkondisi').serialize();
data["idlapkondisi"] = idlapkondisi;
```

Then you can add `data` to your Ajax call as usual.

Comment: but when i am trying to use console.log, the idlapkondisi didnt appear @Glenn Ferrie